# Creating a PWM signal using PIC18F4520

Tags: pic, pwm, proteus, duty-cycle, c18

I am trying to create a 100ms period pwm signal (10Hz) with a PIC18F4520, I followed the PR2 equation to help me create this signal

I have a 20MHz clock frequency with a prescaler of 16 and a PWM period of (100 x 10<sup>-3</sup> s) and when I use these values in this equation:

\$ \Large PR2 = ( \frac{PWM Period}{( TOsc \times 4 \times TMR2 Prescaler )} ) - 1 \$

I get `0x31249`

I am also trying to run this PWM signal at 50% duty cycle [so 50ms off and 50ms on] by using the duty cycle equation:

Duty Cycle = **((CCPR1L << 7 ) | (CCP1CON bits <5:4>) )** \$ \times \$ **TOSC in MHz** \$ \times \$ **Prescale**

Which gives 62500 as a value for the duty cycle.

This whole exercise is for me to learn better about using PWM signals. I am programming the PIC in C18 and simulating it on PROTEUS VSM.

[image]

that is a picture of what the oscilloscope is picking up off the PWM signal which DOES NOT LOOK LIKE 50% duty cycle or 10 Hz frequency.

This is the code that I am using on PROTEUS VSM:

```
include p18cxxx.h           
include pwm.h                   
include timers.h                
pragma config OSC = HS          
pragma config MCLRE = ON             
pragma config WDT = OFF         
pragma config LVP = OFF          
pragma config DEBUG = OFF       
pragma config PBADEN = OFF          
unsigned char period = 0x31249;         // assign PR2 to 31249 used to get 100ms period

unsigned int duty_cycle = 62500;  // used to get 50ms on/off

void main(void)
{ 

    OpenTimer2(TIMER_INT_OFF & T2_PS_1_16 & T2_POST_1_1); 

    OpenPWM1 (period);              

    SetDCPWM1 (duty_cycle);         

    while (1);

}
```

As it can be seen I am using the PWM library as I heard it was easier to work with.

I am sorry if I appear too unacquainted with how questions are made on this forum or as to how I presented my problem.

Comment: `unsigned char period = 0x31249;` That value is far too big for an `unsigned char`, which is possibly part of the problem.

Comment: Even I thought it was way too big and I went with it only not to work , have you got a different value than that? If you do how did you get it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a 100ms PWM period with a 20MHz clock. The maximum will be something like 16ms. You can run the micro slower or use a faster period. Generally the period is not too important and you want to maximize the resolution.

Please read the **datasheet** and **reference manual** sections on the timers carefully, there are too many issues with your understanding.

Also note that you have confused 0x31249 (201289 decimal) with 31249.